# Custom CSS for plugin form

Tags: plugins, css, shortcode, forms

I have a short code that is adding a form to a page. How do I ensure that the CSS for the form is loaded in time with the shortcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check with `the_posts` hook if your shortcode exists and only enqueue the style if so :

```
function check_for_shortcode($posts) {
    if ( empty($posts) )
        return $posts;

    $found = false;

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if ( stripos($post->post_content, '[CHANGE_TO_YOUR_SHORT_CODE') )
            $found = true;
            break;
        }

    if ($found){
        $url = get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_login_Stylesheet',$url.'/my_login_Stylesheet.css' );

    }
    return $posts;
}
add_action('the_posts', 'check_for_shortcode');
```

Comment: So I would store the code in my theme and then call it from the_posts? Would it still be valid if I put the css in my plugin folder? Also, is the_posts called in time? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: just paste this code in your theme's functions.php file, and change the `$url.'/my_login_Stylesheet.css` to reflect the url to your css file in your plugin folder, and change `CHANGE_TO_YOUR_SHORT_CODE` to your actual shortcode

Comment: Wouldn't this only work for the first post found with the short code? It looks like this searches through ALL posts, or does it only search through the post pulled in with the query?

Comment: All posts in current query for all queries

Answer (score 0):

You add the css for this form to your theme's style.css. The css is already there no matter if you have a form or not. That's the easiest solution.

Comment: Is there a ways to do this automatically, via the plugin?

Comment: I don't know. You might be able to find a hook or filter to do this. Have a look at the WordPress sourcecode for that. A different (not recommended!) approach could be reading the active theme's style.css and append the new styles to the file. Personally I would go with the elegant solution proposed by Bainternet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed your styles through a  tag above the short code HTMl.

Comment: But I'd advise against this. @Bainternet's solution is much, much better.